# How if statement works in Perl with a hash argument?

Tags: perl, if-statement, hash

i have this variable:

```
my %permit = (
        "activity" => '',
        "type" => '',
        "sub_type" => '',
        "status" => '',e
        );

    my $permit;
```

and before i have tihis if:

```
if($permit->{activity}){
     print "inside if\n";
}
```

the question is: when the if statement is execute?

Comment: perl does sequential execution. try perl scripts with `use strict; use warnings;` so the interpreter can warn you.

Comment: Instead of `if($permit->{activity})` I think you mean `if($permit{activity})` without `->` since the hash here seems to be `%permit` and not a reference to a hash. To avoid confusion you should probably not use the same name for the two different variables `%permit` and `$permit` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two variables here - `%permit` which is a hash containing key/value pairs and `$permit` which is a scalar and doesn't contain anything.

To look up a value in the hash, you should use the syntax `$permit{activity}` (notice there is no arrow there). The syntax `$permit->{activity}` (with the arrow) attempts to use the scalar `$permit` as a hash **reference** and will return nothing - as `$permit` does not contain a hash reference.

You will never get into your `if` branch as your code is looking at the wrong variable.

This is why it's generally a very bad idea to have two variables of different types with the same name (`%permit` vs `$permit`).

Comment: Also, using `use strict; use warnings;` (as suggested by raul varga in a comment to the OP), the script would have errored out with `Global symbol "$permit" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $permit"?) at...`, indicating that you're in fact using variable `$permit` and not `%permit`.

Comment: Sorry, the comment i referred to was by Rajashekar Reddy M. raul varga was the OP.

Comment: @Silvar: But both `%permit` and `$permit` were already declared.